# Asciifolding with Elasticsearch and Tire in Rails 4 not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, tire

I created a search engine in my rails 4 app that was working great, but I am having a very hard time getting the asciifolding filter to work. My model has a lot of terms with accents which will not come up unless they're spelled exactly right, ie: I want a search for "Rodriguez" to display results with "Rodríguez." I have tried to follow many different examples but for some reason when I reset my database with the following code, the search won't work at all (I don't get an error but nothing comes up regardless of the query).

Here is my model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Tire::Model::Search
    include Tire::Model::Callbacks

    settings :analysis => {
        :analyzer => {
          :default => {
            :tokenizer  => "standard",
            :filter  => ["standard", "asciifolding"]
          }
        }
    } do

        mapping do
          indexes :id, type: 'integer', index: :not_analyzed
          indexes :name, boost: 5, analyzer: 'default'
          indexes :website, index: :not_analyzed
          indexes :price, type: 'integer', index: :not_analyzed
          indexes :artist, boost: 3, analyzer: 'default'
          indexes :company, boost: 4, analyzer: 'default'
          indexes :date, type: 'date', index: :not_analyzed
        end
    end

    def self.search(params)
      tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 12) do
        query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
      end
    end
```

Before testing, I clear the database with:

```
rake db:setup
```

Then I run:

```
rake environment tire:import CLASS=Product FORCE=true
```

I have looked at many different resources including the elasticsearch and tire documentation, but for whatever reason (i am anticipating a stupid mistake) it simply won't work. Small note, to populate my database I have been importing a csv file, but I don't see why this would effect anything, especially considering nothing is coming up in the search in this form (it works fine sans the accent problem when I delete the settings part and just have the mapping block and search method). Do I need to call some sort of Tire.index and import? Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

So I made an edit to the search query which fixed the problem but raised a new one:

```
    def self.search(params)
          tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 12) do
            query { string params[:query], analyzer: :search_analyzer, :default_field => 'name' } if params[:query].present?
          end
        end
```

By identifying a default field, I can now search accent agnostic, but now my search is limited to just the name and I cannot receive results for other indexed attributes that were working previously. Does anyone know how to set multiple default fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is example that I use in production. It's **not solution** to your problem but it will get you off the ground. My code is using [ICU plugin](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-icu-plugin.html) for [icu_folding](http://gibrown.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/three-principles-for-multilingal-indexing-in-elasticsearch/), [shingle_filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/searching-with-shingles/), [multi_field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html) and [Tire](https://github.com/karmi/retire). Also note that [Tire](https://github.com/karmi/retire) is [retired](https://github.com/karmi/retire/wiki/Tire-Retire) since september 2013 and that you should be using [elasticsearch-ruby](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby) or [elasticsearch-rails](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails) if its a new project. With this code I can have autocomplete with cases like `Rod` finding `Rodríguez`.

```
class Profile
  # ...
  include Tire::Model::Persistence
  # I'm also using ES as persistance storage.
  include Tire::Model::DynamicPersistence

  property :title, analyzer: 'snowball', type: :multi_field,
    fields: {
      title: {
        type: 'string',
        boost: 20.0,
        search_analyzer: "autocomplete_search_analyzer",
        index_analyzer: "autocomplete_indexer_analyzer"
      },
      completed: {
        type: 'string',
        boost: 15.0,
        search_analyzer: "autocomplete_search_analyzer",
        index_analyzer: "autocomplete_indexer_analyzer"
    }
  }

  CONFIGURATION = {
    settings: {
      analysis: {
        analyzer: {
          shingle_analyzer: {
            tokenizer: "keyword",
            filter: ["icu_folding", "lowercase", "shingle_filter"]
          },
          sx_index_analyzer: {
            tokenizer: "standard",
            filter: ["icu_folding", "lowercase"]
          },
          sx_search_analyzer: {
            tokenizer: "standard",
            filter: ["icu_folding", "lowercase"]
          }
        },
        filter: {
          shingle_filter: {
            type: "shingle",
            min_shingle_size: 2,
            max_shingle_size: 5
          }
        }

      }
    },

    mappings: {
      profile: {
        "_all" => {
          enabled: true,
          index_analyzer: "sx_index_analyzer",
          search_analyzer: "sx_search_analyzer"
        },

       properties: {
        title: {
         type: "multi_field",
         fields: {
          title: {
            type: "string",
            store: "yes",
            boost: 20.0
            #index_analyzer: "sx_index_analyzer",
            #search_analyzer: "sx_search_analyzer"
          },
          sortable: {
            type: "string",
            index: "analyzed"
          },
          autocomplete: {
            type: "string",
            index_analyzer: "shingle_analyzer",
            boost: 15.0
          },
         }
        }
       }
      }
    }
  }

  def self.rebuild_index
    Tire.index Profile.index_name do
      delete if Profile.index.exists?
      create Profile::CONFIGURATION
    end
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you I don't have time to test this now but I will let you know how it works when I can!

Comment: If you found this to be the right answer, please do mark it as appropriate. Thanks. ;)